# git commit amended locally but pushed to remote now can't sync

Tags: git

I'm using git and messed up the last commit which I had pushed to the remote.

No one else is using the repository just me, so it's fine to rebase if needed.

I had another 1 line change I should have added to the last commit so I staged the change and did `git commit --amend`.  This fixed the commit locally but I now can't push to the remote as the remote still has the bad commit.

How do I correct this? I tried `git remote reset --hard HEAD~1` but I presume I can't just work on a remote directly- do I need to make the changes locally and then push those?

Comment: `git push --force` warning: this will overwrite the remote with the state of the local repo

Comment: yeah it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git push --force
```

this will overwrite the commit in your remote, but be careful! in this case is safe because (as you said) you're the only one using the repo, so go ahead

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Out of interest what is this doing - does it drop any commits ahead of the local one?

Comment: @Yunti remotely: yes, locally: no

Answer (score 0):

In case your server does not allow push --force, you can rebase your amended commit onto origin/master and push that.

```
git rebase origin/master
git push master
```